# What's the encoding difference impeding playback on iOS?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, file-formats

A video used on a website doesn't want to play on iOS devices. The video was encoded by another person using Sony Vegas, with settings similar to what I used before (although I used Adobe Premiere). The video I encoded works, the one from Vegas won't.

I used *ffmpeg* to compare the specs of the videos, and can't spot what's the difference that is impeding playback.

Input #0 (1.mp4) is from Vegas, not working. Input #1 (2.mp4) is from Premiere, working. Any clues? What do we need to change to make it playable?

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : MSNV
    minor_version   : 19529847
    compatible_brands: MSNVmp42isom
    creation_time   : 2013-04-16 18:40:45
  Duration: 00:02:31.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2617 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-16 18:40:45
      handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 40:33 DAR 20:11], 2483 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-04-16 18:40:45
      handler_name    : Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2015-09-03 18:55:57
  Duration: 00:00:10.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2256 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1938 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-03 18:55:57
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-03 18:55:57
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vegas export is

- 60 fps
- NTSC sized raster but with a non-square and weird pixel aspect
- Audio track is first
- File major brand is Sony-specific.

Many confounding factors here.

First try to rewrap

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -c copy -map v -map a -movflags +faststart 1new.mp4
```

If not, render in Vegas at 30 fps and Main profile using the Mainconcept encoder.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Rewrapping did't work, and I'm still not sure what is causing the inability to play exactly. But, I feel the DAR and SAR are the problems, as you described. The metadata and tags I could change, and didn't affect it. 60 fps is ok to shouldn't be a problem. Same with stream order. So the aspect ratios are the ones left. Probably the trouble makers here :D thank you!

Comment: I've had a client for whom my 60 fps export didn't play on iDevices but did after exporting as 30fps. She was testing on an older device, though. So, do check that.